# Concatenate column headers if value in rows below is non-blank

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, formula, textjoin

I have table with data in the format below.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD6km.jpg)
[image]

I want the finished table to have the blank column to be populated like the highlighted one below.

[Finished Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHun2.jpg)
[image]

So, I need a formula or VBA that will return and concatenate the headers of non-blank cells in each row.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  At the very least, a nested `IF()` statement looks like it would work.

Comment: I tried an IF function but was getting errors that it had too many arguments

Answer (score 8):

Use¹ the following as an **array formula**.

```
=TEXTJOIN("-->", TRUE, IF(LEN(C3:I3), C$2:I$2, ""))
```

[image]

**Pre-Excel 2016 versions**

While you could just string together a series of IF statements, a cleaner alternate might be to write a user defined function (aka UDF).

In a standard VBA module code sheet:

```
Function udf_Stitch_Together(r As Range, _
                             h As Range, _
                             Optional d As String = "-->", _
                             Optional blnks As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim s As String, c As Long
    For c = 1 To r.Cells.Count
        If CBool(Len(r.Cells(c).Text)) Then _
            s = s & IIf(Len(s), d, vbNullString) & h.Cells(c).Text
    Next c
    udf_Stitch_Together = s
End Function
```

[image]

---

¹ <sub>The [TEXTJOIN](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) was introduced with Excel 2016 in the following versions:*Excel for Android phones, Excel Mobile, Excel 2016 with Office 365, Excel 2016 for Mac, Excel Online, Excel for iPad, Excel for iPhone and Excel for Android tablet.*</sub>

Comment: Clever! I was playing with `TextJoin()` but couldn't find a nice way to only fill cells with a value.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010 and it's not recognizing the TEXTJOIN formula.  But looks like that is exactly what I want to do.  Any similar formula for my version of excel?

Comment: That would depend on how many **actual** columns you want to examine. Seven columns is not out of scope for even seven nested IF conditions but there are shorter formulas.

Comment: There are 10 columns