# Distinguishing cells in a row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel sheet as shown in the picture

[image: Excel sheet snippet]

I want to get the years where there is a x symbol for each row.

Comment: You can query that table and filter out anything that doesn't have an X

Comment: Can you please clarify what the output should look like? Is it a new row with the year, eg. "1920" if any of the rows have an "x"? Or are you looking for one cell listing the years that have an "x", e.g. cell value = "1920,1921,1928"?

Comment: The second one- All the values that have x in it

Comment: Basically the textjoin function can do the work but it does not seem to work in 2016 version

Comment: What formula did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: I tried      =TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,C2:BL2) and its giving a #NAME?  error

Comment: textjoin is only available in 2016 if an office 365 description exists. have a look at https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/ they include an example how to build a custom concatenate function using VBA. it should be possible to add the required condition (i.e. "x" in the specific column).

Comment: see here for a TEXTJOIN UDF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532189/vlookup-with-multiple-criteria-returning-values-in-one-cell

Comment: or this more specific answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104790/concatenate-column-headers-if-value-in-rows-below-is-non-blank

Comment: Without native TEXTJOIN  you will need vba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround which will not be as "clean" as using textjoin or a custom function would be using some additional space in the spreadsheet and first preparing the dates and then joining them via a regular concatenate function

[image: basis example]

Formula in Cell B4 would be

```
=IF(B2="x",B1&" ","")
```

Basically  the x is replaced with the date and the seperator you want (here just blank)

Formula in Cell H4 would be

```
=CONCATENATE(B4,C4,D4,E4,F4)
```

Here you join the dates (unfortunately range selection like B4:F4 is not possible).

It is a little bit "ugly" but will get the job done.

Comment: Thank you. I used VBA for the same and it gives very good results